# PATINDEX with SOUNDEX

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Want to search the string using PATINDEX and SOUNDEX.

I have the following table with some sample data to search the given string using `PATINDEX` and `SOUNDEX`.

```
create table tbl_pat_soundex
(
    col_str varchar(max)
);

insert into tbl_pat_soundex values('Smith A Steve');
insert into tbl_pat_soundex values('Steve A Smyth');
insert into tbl_pat_soundex values('A Smeeth Stive');
insert into tbl_pat_soundex values('Steve Smith A');
insert into tbl_pat_soundex values('Smit Steve A');
```

**String to search:-** 'Smith A Steve'

```
SELECT col_str,PATINDEX('%Smith%',col_str) [Smith],PATINDEX('%A%',col_str) [A],PATINDEX('%Steve%',col_str) [Steve]
FROM tbl_pat_soundex
```

Getting Output:

```
col_str         Smith   A   Steve
---------------------------------
Smith A Steve   1       7   9
Steve A Smyth   0       7   1
A Smeeth Stive  0       1   0
Steve Smith A   7       13  1
Smit Steve A    0       12  6
```

Expected Output:

```
col_str         Smith   A   Steve
---------------------------------
Smith A Steve   1       7   9
Steve A Smyth   9       7   1
A Smeeth Stive  3       1   10
Steve Smith A   7       13  1
Smit Steve A    1       12  6
```

## Tried:

```
SELECT col_str,
        PATINDEX('%'+soundex('Smith')+'%',soundex(col_str)) [Smith],
        PATINDEX('%'+soundex('A')+'%',soundex(col_str)) [A],
        PATINDEX('%'+soundex('Steve')+'%',soundex(col_str)) [Steve]
FROM tbl_pat_soundex
```

But getting unexpected result:

```
col_str         Smith   A   Steve
---------------------------------
Smith A Steve   1       0   0
Steve A Smyth   0       0   1
A Smeeth Stive  0       1   0
Steve Smith A   0       0   1
Smit Steve A    1       0   0
```

**Note**: I have `100 Millions` of records in the table to search for.

Comment: Why are you expecting `10` for `PATINDEX('%Steve%','A Smeeth Stive')` and `3` for `PATINDEX('%Smith%','A Smeeth Stive')`? `'Stive' <> 'Steve'` and `'Smeeth' <> 'Smoth'`. `PATINDEX` doesn't wok with sounds, it works with characters.

Comment: \*`Smith` Seems like you might want to split your string into parts (separated at a whitespace (`' '`)) and then `SOUNDEX` each of those. At a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option, not sure how it would perform with 100 million records considering all that you need to do.  You'll have to test that out.

At a high level how I understand this is you basically need

- Search all words in a string based on the words of another string
- Returning the character starting position in the original string where that word equals or sounds like the search word.

You can use [DIFFERENCE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/difference-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for the comparison:

> DIFFERENCE compares two different SOUNDEX values, and returns an
>   integer value. This value measures the degree that the SOUNDEX values
>   match, on a scale of 0 to 4. A value of 0 indicates weak or no
>   similarity between the SOUNDEX values; 4 indicates strongly similar,
>   or even identically matching, SOUNDEX values.

You'll need to split the string based on the space ' ' and since you're 2008 you'd have to roll your own function.

I used the XML function from here, https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings, for my examples, you'll obviously need to adjust if you have your own or want to use something different:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

I switched and use table variables to show the example, I would suggest not doing that with the amount of data you have and create and use physical tables.

Option 1 - Not dynamic:

```
DECLARE @tbl_pat_soundex TABLE
    (
        [col_str] VARCHAR(MAX)
    );

INSERT INTO @tbl_pat_soundex
VALUES ( 'Smith A Steve' )
,( 'Steve A Smyth' )
,( 'A Smeeth Stive' )
,( 'Steve Smith A' )
,( 'Smit Steve A' )

SELECT DISTINCT [aa].[col_str]
              , MAX([aa].[Smith]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [aa].[col_str] ) AS [Smith]
              , MAX([aa].[A]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [aa].[col_str] ) AS [A]
              , MAX([aa].[Steve]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [aa].[col_str] ) AS [Steve]
FROM   (
           SELECT      [a].[col_str]
                     , CASE WHEN DIFFERENCE([b].[item], 'Smith') = 4 THEN
                                CHARINDEX([b].[item], [a].[col_str])
                            ELSE 0
                       END AS [Smith]
                     , CASE WHEN DIFFERENCE([b].[item], 'A') = 4 THEN
                                CHARINDEX([b].[item], [a].[col_str])
                            ELSE 0
                       END AS [A]
                     , CASE WHEN DIFFERENCE([b].[item], 'Steve') = 4 THEN
                                CHARINDEX([b].[item], [a].[col_str])
                            ELSE 0
                       END AS [Steve]
           FROM        @tbl_pat_soundex [a]
           CROSS APPLY [dbo].[SplitStrings_XML]([a].[col_str], ' ') [b]
       ) AS [aa];
```

- Using the function we split the string into individual words
- Then we use a case statement to check the DIFFERENCE value
- If that DIFFERENCE value equals 4 we then return the CHARINDEX value of the original word against string.
- If doesn't equal we return 0

Then from there it's a matter of getting the max value of each based on the original string:

```
          , MAX([aa].[Smith]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [aa].[col_str] ) AS [Smith]
          , MAX([aa].[A]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [aa].[col_str] ) AS [A]
          , MAX([aa].[Steve]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [aa].[col_str] ) AS [Steve]
```

To get you your final results:

[image]

Option 2 - Dynamic with a pivot:

We'll declare the string we want to search, split that out and search for those individuals words in the original string and then pivot the results.

```
--This example is using global temp tables as it's showing how
--to build a dynamic pivot
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tbl_pat_soundex') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE [##tbl_pat_soundex];

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tbl_col_str_SearchString') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE [##tbl_col_str_SearchString];

CREATE TABLE [##tbl_pat_soundex]
    (
        [col_str] VARCHAR(MAX)
    );

INSERT INTO [##tbl_pat_soundex]
VALUES ( 'Smith A Steve' )
     , ( 'Steve A Smyth' )
     , ( 'A Smeeth Stive' )
     , ( 'Steve Smith A' )
     , ( 'Smit Steve A' );

--What are you searching for?
DECLARE @SearchString NVARCHAR(200);
SET @SearchString = N'Smith A Steve';

--We build a table we load with every combination of the words from the string and the words from the SearchString for easier comparison.
CREATE TABLE [##tbl_col_str_SearchString]
    (
        [col_str] NVARCHAR(MAX)
      , [col_str_value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
      , [SearchValue] NVARCHAR(200)
    );

--Load that table for comparison
--split our original string into individual words
--also split our search string into individual words and give me all combinations.
INSERT INTO [##tbl_col_str_SearchString] (
                                             [col_str]
                                           , [col_str_value]
                                           , [SearchValue]
                                         )
            SELECT      DISTINCT [a].[col_str]
                               , [b].[item]
                               , [c].[item]
            FROM        [##tbl_pat_soundex] [a]
            CROSS APPLY [dbo].[SplitStrings_XML]([a].[col_str], ' ') [b]
            CROSS APPLY [dbo].[SplitStrings_XML](@SearchString, ' ') [c]
            ORDER BY    [a].[col_str];

--Then we can easily compare each word and search word for those that match or sound alike using DIFFERNCE()
SELECT [col_str], [col_str_value], [SearchValue], CASE WHEN DIFFERENCE([col_str_value], [SearchValue]) = 4 THEN CHARINDEX([col_str_value], [col_str]) ELSE 0 END AS [Match] FROM ##tbl_col_str_SearchString

--Then we can pivot on it
--and we will need to make it dynamic since we are not sure what what @SearchString could be.
DECLARE @PivotSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @pivotColumn NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @pivotColumn = N'[' + REPLACE(@SearchString, ' ', '],[') + N']';

SET @PivotSQL = N'SELECT * FROM (
SELECT [col_str], [SearchValue], CASE WHEN DIFFERENCE([col_str_value], [SearchValue]) = 4 THEN CHARINDEX([col_str_value], [col_str]) ELSE 0 END AS [Match] FROM ##tbl_col_str_SearchString
) aa
PIVOT (MAX([Match]) FOR [SearchValue] IN (' + @pivotColumn
                + N')) AS MaxMatch
ORDER BY [MaxMatch].[col_str]
';

--Giving us the final results.
EXEC sp_executesql @PivotSQL
```

Comment: Can we do it in a single `WHERE` clause? Because it's taking too much time to execute.